# Freeform Next - Dynamic Recipients

Tags: solspace, solspace-freeform-next

I'm a little confused at how to use the dynamic recipients parameter for Freeform next.

I've provided the emails using `dynamic_notification_recipients="email_1|email_2"` and specified `dynamic_notification_template="standard"` but there doesn't seem to be anymore documentation about how it's chosen. What do I have to name the field? What value do I have to provide, the email address or something else? Or do I need to use this in combination with the recipients field in composer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you might be mixing up some of the notification types Freeform Next offers. Currently there are [5 different ways to send email notifications](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/common-issues/#email-notification-options):

1. To admin email address(es) for the form (set inside *Notify* area of Composer)
2. To a predefined select menu/radios of email addresses (and labels) for the user to choose ([Dynamic Recipients field type](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/fields-field-types/#fields-dynamic-recipients)).
3. To the user submitting the form, with the email addresses specified/selected in the [Email field type](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/fields-field-types/#fields-email).
4. To a user-defined email address (e.g Tell-a-Friend form), with the email addresses specified/selected in the [Email field type](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/fields-field-types/#fields-email).
5. At template level with the [dynamic_notification_recipients](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/form/#param-dynamicnotificationrecipients) parameter.

If you want to setup a predefined list of email options for a user to choose from to notify, then just create a Dynamic Recipients field and place it/set it up in Composer. Nothing else necessary.

If you are wanting to pass an email address(es) to your form at template level to be notified, then you'll want to use the [dynamic_notification_recipients](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/form/#param-dynamicnotificationrecipients) parameter approach, where you specify the email(s) and the notification template, and Freeform will take care of the rest. :)

Comment: Thanks, it's the `dynamic_notification_recipients` parameter I'm using but I just don't know how it selects which email to send to? It doesn't add any fields to the form and because I'm using the render method I can't add any fields within the tags.

** EDIT **
Or am I thinking about this parameter wrong, it doesn't allow us to pick one of them, it just sends the notification to both?

Comment: The complete code to use this feature looks like this (both parameters are required together): `dynamic_notification_recipients="admin@example.com|support@example.com"
dynamic_notification_template="test.html"`

Comment: I've already got both parameters supplied as mentioned in the original question. I'm just confused as to how Freeform selects which one to send to? Or as asked in my comment, am I thinking about this wrong and it just sends to both emails specified? Rather than picking one?

Comment: Yes, it'll send to both email addresses specified. :)